# How can I train a neural net on Mathematica to predict text output from input?

Tags: neural-networks

I want to feed a neural net examples like this:

Input: I w e n t to the store

Output: I went to the store

Input: I was p l a y i n g with my friends

Output: I was playing with my friends

etc.

And have it learn to generate the correct output given that kind of input string. Is there a simple function I could use to implement this or is this more complicated?

I also want to train another one to do a similar task like so:

Input String: "that. I was saying yesterday..."
Output: "I was saying yesterday..."

Input: "that old. When I said to him..."
Output: "When I said to him..."

Comment: OK so what have you tried so far? How big is your training set? Can you share it with us? Typically: no code, no data -> no answers.

Comment: Programming wise, I plan to generate a lot of sentences with permutations like I explained above. Meaning, the first word of the sentence "I w e n t to the store" then second word: "I went t o the store", third word, etc. So the training data could be very large if I just take words randomly from a dictionary, put them together, and then create these input permutation errors.

I'm not knowledgable enough to even know what to do machine learning wise (what algorithm to use, whether or not to use a language model or something pretrained, type of neural net to choose, I have absolutely no clue)

Comment: This is why I was asking whether or not Mathematica had some meta or super function which could handle the bulk of that work, just takes in input, output strings, and is able to train and generate predictions, or at least some approximation of that.

Comment: E.g. RobustFill: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/blog/deep-learning-program-synthesis/?wt.mc_id=MCR_378116_FB1

Comment: I also tried Predict[{"I w e n t to the store" -> "I went to the store"}] but got the error: Predict: Incompatible variable type (Numerical) and variable value (I went to the store).

Comment: I also tried converting the input and output sentences like "I went to the store" to every alphabet character to a number and joining it in a full number (as opposed to an array of numbers), then feeding those into Predict, (but only a few examples) and didn't get any good results.

Comment: Your question is far too broad and the problem too complex for this venue. Typically here we discuss solutions to specific code problems in the context of existing implementations. I suggest that you get yourself to a level of knowledge where you can decide about a strategy, attempt it, and then ask about any specific implementation problem. There are some contributors with deep expertise in machine learning here who would be happy to lend a hand, but they typically do not have the time to take on your project and build your solution for you from the ground up.

Comment: Oh, sorry I did not at all mean that someone take on this project and implement it from the ground up. I was just trying to find out whether this was something that would actually be doable with a superfunction or two. But it seems it's not possible, thanks either way for the info!